# HTML div is ignoring div for margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

This is kinda confusing to explain but I'll give it a shot. Basically, I have 3 'main' divs on one page. The first is the navbar, the second is a search box and the third is a content box.

I want them to be one under the other, so navbar > search box > content box. The problem I have is that when I set `margin-top: 10px;` to the content box it goes directly underneath the navigation bar and not the search box. It seems to be ignoring the search box and I can't for the life of work out why. I'm pretty new to all this so please bear with me if this is a newbie mistake.

Thank you!

```
<body>

<div id="navbar">
        <img class="navbar" src="images/homebutton.png" />
        <img class="navbar" src="images/e-3button.png" />
        <img class="navbar" src="images/resignedbutton.png" />
        <img class="navbar" src="images/firedbutton.png" />
        <img class="navbar" src="images/desertersbutton.png" />
        <img class="navbar" src="images/mosrosterbutton.png" />
        <img src="images/divider.png" />
        <p><script language="JavaScript">dT();</script></p>
</div>

<div id="search">
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
        <b><p>Search</p></b>
        <form action="" id="search_habbo">            
            <input type="text" name="habbo_name" id="habbo_name" size="30" required>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="send" id="send">
        </form>
    <div id="search_results">
        <div id="loadingimage">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
</body>

#navbar {
    background: url(images/navbarbg.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

#search {
    display: block;
    width: 920px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -462px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
}



 #content {
        width: 920px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -462px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), inset 0 -5px 5px -5px #000000;
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste your HTML as well

Answer (score 3):

it's ignoring the search box because you have this for #content

```
postion: absolute;
```

change it to

```
position: relative;
```

or add something like

```
top: 40px;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want them one on top of the other, then delete these lines of code:

#search

```
position: absolute;
top: 65px;
left: 50%;
```

#content

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
```

Also, why these:

```
margin-left: -462px;
```

Delete those too

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, absolute positioning is the problem - I tend to avoid it for all general positioning.

Take a look at this link, it has some really handy examples for positioning boxes - I still make reference to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/css-positioning.html